# How to give data from right to left in textfield?

Tags: objective-c, uiwebview

in my application im using html page ,in that page i have one text field now i want to give data from right to left (because in hebrew language allignment is from right to left) please help me thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For RTL text field, you can use the HTML `dir` attribute or the with `dir="RTL"` `direction` attribute in CSS with `direction: rtl`. You can use these properties on most visual HTML elements, not just on text fields.

```
<textarea dir="rtl"></textarea>
```